# Unrecognized day of week error in python-Cron tab

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, cron

I am working on a Django app. I was using crontab for jobs in background. Here is an example of my code

```
from crontab import cronTab
pddays=[1,2,3,4]
cron = CronTab(user=username)
job = cron.new(command=“curl http://***********”)
job.dow.on(str(pddays)[1:-1])
cron.write()
```

But when I execute it I get the error -

> ValueError: Unrecognized Day off week ‘1,2,3,4’

Comment: What if you try: `job.dow.on(*pddays)` ?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and that totally works. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The crontab library expects arguments that are either the integer represent the day (0-6) or its abbreviation as a string ('SUN', 'FRI' etc...), so you can unpack your `pddays` integer list for it:

```
job.dow.on(*pddays)
```